# How to add constraints in orientdb

Tags: sql, orientdb, orientdb2.2

I have a table named posts with some fields and I would like to restrict the field 'type'  to accept only 3 strings 'video' 'photo' and 'slideshow' 
how to do it?

 I tried

```
    alter property Post.type add constraint check 
(post.type in ('video','photo','slideshow'));
```

but it is not working

how to add a constraint in orientdb like

```
alter table post add constraint check(type in ('video','photo','slideshow'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by addind a REGEXP on the property :

```
CREATE CLASS Post Extends V
CREATE PROPERTY Post.type STRING
Alter PROPERTY Post.type REGEXP "video|photo|slideshow"
```

Hope it helps